# Docker stuck on apt-get update on M1 Mac (Apple Silicone)

Tags: node.js, docker, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have a docker file, that is built from the base image `node:bullseye-slim`

Following is the basic docker file

```
FROM  --platform=linux/amd64  node:bullseye-slim
RUN cat /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install curl -y
```

Initially I was not using `--platform=linux/amd64`, and the build completed without an error, but this resulted it in building the image in `arm/64` architecture which resulted in problems running the image. Based on my search I found out adding `--platform=linux/amd64` will make sure the image is built on x86 architecture as required by one of the libraries I use.

So I decided to add `--platform=linux/amd64`. But since then when ever I try to build the image it gets stuck on `RUN apt-get update -y` step.
I have left it running over night (over 10 hours) and still it stuck on the step.

I also ran the build with he flag `--progress=plain` to get more detailed logs but there are no logs for `apt-get update` and it seems to be just stuck on the step.

The output is as following

```
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 30B
#1 transferring dockerfile: 331B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 34B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:bullseye-slim
#3 DONE 1.2s

#4 [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/node:bullseye-slim@sha256:22a517a42af0f2bf961e12daa3a940244e5ddf450c6da6c0e245b652f1027713
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [2/8] RUN cat /etc/apt/sources.list
#5 CACHED

#6 [internal] load build context
#6 transferring context: 757B done
#6 DONE 0.0s

#7 [3/8] RUN apt-get update -y
```

I am running this on the new MacBook Pro 14 inch with M1 Pro chip.

I have tried running `docker system prune -a` and trying building again, and still gets stuck. I have tried using `node:bullseye` instead of `node:bullseye-slim` but it still got stuck. If I remove `--platform=linux/amd64` the build completes with no issues.

Any idea what the issue is and how can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So,
It seems like restarting docker worked, I can't believe I did not think of that before. I did system prune but never restarted docker.

For any one else facing similar issue, try restarting docker

Comment: Thank you, can't believe that also worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Use that platform with `arm64` like

`FROM  --platform=linux/arm64/v8  node:bullseye-slim`

You can search the exact platform name with `arm64` on the docker hub against each image and use that to make it work in Mac Apple Silicone

[image]
[image]